# OpenCL kernel queueing delays

Tags: opencl, gpu, gpgpu

I have a gigantic pile of data, 100GB. I only have 1GB of Video memory. I need to queue my kernel many times with MaxWorkgroupSize chunks. That's going to be ~10000 kernel queueings and 100 Memory transfers. How badly will this affect my performance time? Also, is there a faster way of processing so much data? Would I just be better off running on my cpu with 8 threads, because then there is no data transfer and kernel delays. I'm asking before I code the thing because I want to make sure I have the right approach.

Comment: Go on with OpenCL, specially if you are going to process the data in the same manner (apply an algorithm that does not change its inner behaviour, only the data input)

Comment: What sort of operations/algorithm do you need to do on your data?

Comment: Where is your original 100GB stored?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the nature of the work.  GPUs are SIMD machines.  If you are typically doing the same thing for each item (e.g. branches are normally going the same place for each work item), then that bodes well for a GPU.  Even so, 8 thread CPU has OpenCL implementations for it as well.  Also, in environments like Intel's embedded GPU (AMD too?) you should consider the CL_MEM_USE_HOST_PTR flag on the memory buffer. You can use it to get a zero-copy overhead.

Comment: I have 1 GPU (AMD) and each bit of work basically amounts to a (random) nearby cell lookup and then some math. There are no branches. Also because the cell lookups are basically random, I know that screws with the GPU memory coalescing. Is it possible to just get the GPU to use the system RAM for it's operations... that would solve all the transfers.

Comment: You won't get zero-copy with a discrete GPU, but I wouldn't fret that. If your kernel is non-trivial, the transfer time can be dominated by the computation. I would try it first and see where you land (unless this is a huge investment in time), then optimize.  The GPU should have its own cache; so that should protect against the random accesses. If not, then consider harder stuff like vector data types (e.g. int2, int4, ...) or shared local memory. That stuff tends to be really system dependent though.

Comment: Once you get everything working you can improve it by overlapping memory transfer and compute. Basically, you'll be uploading the data for the next operation and downloading the data from the previous operation while you're doing the compute for the current operation. But again, get it working first before adding this.

Answer (score 0):

Multiple enqueueing of same kernel doesn't impose any performance hit per enqueue in comparison to single kernel run. More to say, it becomes a little bit faster due to caching.

Also, you can run your code on CPU & GPU simultaneously, as both are OpenCL-compatible devices.

Your Device can use memory objects, allocated from Host's RAM (CL_MEM_ALLOC_HOST_PTR & CL_MEM_USE_HOST_PTR flags in clCreateBuffer() function). Anyway, memory transfers may not be the bottleneck.